# How Can I Apply JQuery To This Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm relatively newer to Javascript and Jquery.
I want to ask a simple question. I'm working on blogger platform and using a custom template.
Below is a Jquery code snippet for adding and removing some classes on a slider from a fetched plugin when we give category box [slideshow-v2] in that plugin.

```
"slideshow-v2" === a.options.postType &&
    (750 > $(window).width() && (
            $("#intro").remove(), $("#intro").css(
            {
                height: "0px"
            })), d("#jms-slideshow", a.$el).append(
            F), $("#intro").css(
        {
            padding: "0px 0px 160px 0px",
            background: "url(https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-TXuyvglUfBk/V8fyEoS_OFI/AAAAAAAADmY/AprIWLTTMLUR7ULYIk-iBslvZNdaPG5hQCLcB/s1600/Home_Part_Background.jpg) 50% -75px no-repeat fixed"
        }), $("#ab-menu").addClass(
            "addOpacity"), $("#ab-menu").addClass(
            "fix"),
        $(window).bind("scroll", function()
        {
            $(window).scrollTop();
            $("#ab-menu").addClass("addOpacity");
            $("#ab-menu").addClass("fix")
        }), $("#jms-slideshow").jmslideshow($
            .extend(!0,
            {
                jmpressOpts:
                {
                    animation:
                    {
                        transitionDuration: "1.8s"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                autoplay: !0,
                bgColorSpeed: "1.5s",
                interval: 6E3,
                arrows: !0
            })));
```

Now I've tweaked the template and directly creating a slider. Below is the code for it.

```
<div class='slide' id='intro'>
<section class='jms-slideshow' id='jms-slideshow'>
<div class='step' data-color='color-1'>
<div class='jms-content'>
  <h3>Some Headline</h3> 
<div class='linetop'/>
<p>Washmally Washmally</p>
<a class='jms-link' href='#'>Read more</a>
</div>
<img src='https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-s7ipZ41jnTo/V8vJH0inFnI/AAAAAAAADng/p-Y9iI3xT7E27O0DdobhQ9OR1tVIF8N7wCLcB/s1600/Home1%2B%25281%2529.jpg'/></div>
</section>
</div>
```

So now the Slider is working but its design and classes are manipulated. I want to apply the above JQuery code for the below slider. How I can do this.
Thanks